# Are imports actually performed if you don't use the imported data

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

Must be a dumb question...but anyways. Are imports actually performed when you don't use the data that you imported.

For example, you have one file that contains this:

```
import one from './one';
import two from './two';
import three from './three';

const my_imports = {
  one,
  two,
  three,
};

export default my_imports;
```

And another place where you import this stuff:

`import my_imports from 'path/my_imports';`

So you proceed to use `my_imports.one` somewhere in the code.

The question is. When "compiling" this with webpack will it actually perform the `import two from './two';` and `import three from './three';`?

I hope this makes sense :D Just wondering...

Comment: I dont know if this is a custom option or if it is by default , but webpack will take care of unused variables / imports etc

Answer (score 2):

Surely, it's a question that every new developer thinks of it at least for once.

Yes, `import does work` either any `package` or `imported data` is then `used or not`. You may test it by:

1. Importing any package in your project with wrong path.
2. Importing any data from somewhere which was an empty data/obj while exporting.

Comment: I meant in a strictly webpack context. Will it perform a Tree Shaking in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure but it should import in that case too.